# Can I use "of" to mean "caused by"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions

For instance, can I say:

> I'm not sure if it was a deception of the moon, but the field looked
>   brown.

In this case, "deception of the moon" means "illusion caused by the moon". Is it common to use "of" in that way?

Comment: There's the idiomatic set phrase [*a trick of the light*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22trick+of+the+light%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but you can't naturally generalize that preposition usage to other contexts.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=rNgcBAAAQBAJ&dq=%22trick+of+the+moon%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDsQ6AEwA2oVChMI-dDqwpeSxwIVQ6QeCh395gY5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure if it was a deception of the moon, but the field looked brown.

I find the sentence acceptable provided that you recognise that you are anthropomorphising the moon and assuming that it can intentionally deceive you.

I don't think you can generalise from that example but, in my personal opinion, it works in the specific case you give.

I don't however agree that it means 'caused by'. I would read it as meaning 'perpetrated by'.

I accept that others may disagree.

Comment: I don't mean to imply it's in any way unacceptable.

Comment: @TimRomano - Ah, apologies. I'll edit.

Comment: @chasly from the UK: No apology required. :)

Answer (score 2):

'of' there does not mean so much "caused by" but rather 'pertaining to'.  Compare "sleight of hand"; 'of hand' refers to the *kind* of deception.